# Hitting time for a random walk with non constant steps

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, geometric-probability

Consider the sequence of random variables defined by $X_0= 0$ and $X_{i+1} = X_i + U_i$, where $U_i$ are iid with uniform law on the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ (in dimension $d$). Define $T = \min\{t, \|X_t\|>R\}$.
What can we say about the law of $T$? A bound for $\mathbb{P}(T<t)$ would be particularly appreciated.

Thank you.